# How to use AsyncRoute after migration from angular2.dart to angular.dart 4.0.0+2?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to migrate from angular2.dart to angular.dart 4.0.0+2 but I face some problems.

I get an exception after loading of deferred component.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
EXCEPTION: Bad state: Could not find a component factory for C2Component.
STACKTRACE: 
package:angular/src/di/reflector.dart 35:7                                  getComponent.<fn>
dart:core                                                                   _AssertionError._evaluateAssertion
package:angular/src/di/reflector.dart 33:10                                 getComponent
package:angular/src/core/linker/component_resolver.dart 33:23               ReflectorComponentResolver.resolveComponentSync
package:angular_router/src/utils.dart 41:26                                 getComponentAnnotations
package:angular_router/src/route_registry.dart 127:23                       RouteRegistry.configFromComponent
package:angular_router/src/route_config/route_config_normalizer.dart 12:16  normalizeRouteConfig.loader


-----async gap-----
dart:async                                                                 _Completer.completeError
package:angular_router/src/route_config/route_config_normalizer.dart 14:5  normalizeRouteConfig.loader


-----async gap-----
dart:async                                                                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:angular_router/src/route_config/route_config_normalizer.dart 10:27      normalizeRouteConfig.loader
package:angular_router/src/rules/route_handlers/async_route_handler.dart 18:43  AsyncRouteHandler.resolveComponentType
package:angular_router/src/route_registry.dart 390:42                           RouteRegistry._generate.<fn>
package:angular_router/src/instruction.dart 242:46                              UnresolvedInstruction.resolveComponent


-----async gap-----
dart:async                                          new Future.microtask
package:angular_router/src/instruction.dart 238:57  UnresolvedInstruction.resolveComponent
package:angular_router/src/router.dart 209:24       Router._settleInstruction
package:angular_router/src/router.dart 227:10       Router._navigate
package:angular_router/src/router.dart 204:16       Router.navigateByInstruction.<fn>
dart:async                                          _ZoneDelegate.runUnary
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 185:21   NgZone._runUnary
dart:async                                          _Future._addListener.<fn>
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 161:11   NgZone._scheduleMicrotask.<fn>
dart:async                                          _ZoneDelegate.run
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 175:21   NgZone._run


-----async gap-----
dart:async                                                    _Future.then
package:angular_router/src/router.dart 201:62                 Router.navigateByInstruction
package:angular_router/src/directives/router_link.dart 94:18  RouterLink.onClick
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 594:38          AppView.eventHandler1.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async                                                    _ZoneDelegate.run
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 175:21             NgZone._run
dart:async                                                    _CustomZone.runGuarded
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 311:23             NgZone.runGuarded
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 594:14          AppView.eventHandler1.<fn>
package:angular/src/debug/debug_app_view.dart 164:44          DebugAppView.eventHandler1.<fn>

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Bad state: Could not find a component factory for C2Component.
```

As I understand `angular_router:1.0.2` lib does not need critical changes like in [migration to angular 5+ routing](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular_router/g3doc/migration_guide.md). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I use `dart sdk:1.24.3, angular:4.0.0+2, angular_router:1.0.2`.

And here is the [link for the test repo](https://github.com/danbilbo/angular-dart-routing-lazy-loading).

Thanks .

UPDATE

Here is previous version of lazy loading

```
import 'package:lazy_loading_ng2/mycomponent2.dart' deferred as c2;

@Component(
  ... ,
  directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
)
@RouteConfig(const [
  ... ,
  const AsyncRoute(
    path: '/c2',
    name: 'C2',
    loader: f,
  ),
])
class AppComponent {}

f() => c2.loadLibrary().then((_) => c2.C2Component);
```

I found that component needs to call initReflector() of it's template. The solution was [here](https://github.com/devkabiir/myblog/blob/master/lib/app_component.dart).

I import the template of lazy component:

```
// ignore: uri_has_not_been_generated
import 'package:lazy_loading_ng2/mycomponent2.template.dart' deferred as c2t;
```

And change the loader function:

```
f() =>
    c2t.loadLibrary()
        .then((_) => c2t.initReflector())
        .then((_) => c2t.C2Component);
```

Comment: can you provide any code snippets? You should try using ComponentFactory if possible